# whether meta tag will support phonegap using android

Tags: android

I am new to phonegap .I am developing application using android using phone gap.I had given meta tag in html .In landscape mode its coming properly but potrait mode some spaces are coming can anybody help to solve problem?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
      <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Thanks